# After changing to a float: "Cannot confirm float from string"

Tags: java

Hey so here is my code:

```
if(repeat)
    {

    Guesses++;

    String Input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number between 0 and 10. So far you have had " + Guesses + " guesses.");
    Float.parseFloat(Input);

    if(**Input > RandomNum**)
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Too small.");
        }
    else if(if(repeat)
    {

    Guesses++;

    String Input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number between 0 and 10. So far you have had " + Guesses + " guesses.");
    Float.parseFloat(Input);

    if(Input > RandomNum)
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Too small.");
        }
    else if(Input = RandomNum)
        {)
```

(This is just part of it)
The Text with the **'s is where I get the error. It says

- The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) String, float

Although I (think) I changed the Input, to a float *(Float.parseFloat(Input);)*
So do you know what the problem is? (If this has already been answered then can you give me a link?)

Comment: Try following java naming conventions

Comment: Try posting the *actual* error message in your title, instead of just making one up. If you want the right answer you need to ask the right question. Also try posting code that actually compiles, instead of just nonsense.

Comment: In Java, when you declare a variable to be a type, it will always be that type (or, for a class, a subclass of that type).  So `Input` will always be a `String`.  There is no way to make it become an `int` or `float` at run time.  If you're only used to languages like JavaScript or PHP where you can change variable types at will, you'll have to start thinking differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Float.parseFloat(Input);
```

doesn't change the input. [It parses a `String` and creates a `float` from its representaion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat%28java.lang.String%29). Assign its result to a variable and use that to compare

```
float parsedValue = Float.parseFloat(Input);

if(parsedValue > RandomNum)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for inequalities, however when I set them equal in the "if" statement I get this error:Type mismatch: cannot convert from float to boolean

Comment: @user2789610 Are you checking equality with `==` or setting one to the other with `=`?

Answer (score 3):

`Float.parseFloat(String input)` returns a `float`, it doesn't convert a runtime object into another type, as no method does it in Java.

You should save the returned value somewhere and use it instead:

```
float floatInput = Float.parseFloat(input);
if (floatInput > randomNum)
...
```